# What obscure/semantic differences should I be aware of when evaluating SSE against Fetch with readable streams?

Tags: http, streaming, fetch-api, server-sent-events

I have a scenario where I need to deliver realtime firehoses of events (<30-50/sec max) for dashboard and config-screen type contexts.

While I'll be using WebSockets for some of the scenarios that require bidirectional I/O, I'm having a bit of a bikeshed/architecture-astronaut/analysis paralysis lockup about whether to use Server-Sent Events or Fetch with readable streams for the read-only endpoints I want to develop.

I have no particular vested interest in picking one approach over the other, and the backends aren't using any frameworks or libraries that express opinionation about using one or the other approach, so I figure I might as well put my hesitancy to use and ask:

**Are there any intrinsic benefits to picking SSE over streaming Fetch?**

The only fairly minor caveat I'm aware of with Fetch is that if I'm manually building the HTTP response (say from a C daemon exposing some status info) then I have to manage response chunking myself. That's quite straightforward.

Comment: Clarification: I don't think this is asking multiple questions. I'm open to suggestions about how I can improve its focus.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've discovered one unintuitive gotcha of exactly the sort I was trying to dig out of the woodwork:

**When using HTTP/1.1 (aka plain HTTP), Chrome specially allows up to 255 WebSocket connections per domain, completely independently of its maximum of 15 normal (Fetch)/SSE connections.**

Read all about it: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/e5a38eddbdf45d7563a00d019debd11b803af1bb/net/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc#52

This is of course irrelevant when using HTTP2, where you typically get 100 parallel streams to work with (that **(IIUC)** are shared by all types of connections - Fetch, SSE, WebSockets, etc).

I find it remarkable that **almost every SO question about connection limits doesn't talk about the 255-connection WebSockets limit!** It's been around for 5-6 years!! Use the source, people! :D

I do have to say that this situation is very annoying though. It's reasonably straightforward to "bit-bang" (for want of a better term) HTTP and SSE using `printf` from C (accept connection, ignore all input, immediately `dprintf` HTTP header, proceed to send updates), while WebSockets requires handshake processing, *and* SHA1, *and* MD5, *and* input XORing. For tinkering, prototyping and throwaway code (that'll probably stick around for a while...), the simplicity of SSE is hard to beat. You don't even need to use chunked-encoding with it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about technical differences between SSE and fetch. Maybe you should ask a "are there any websockets connections limits" question, and post this as a self-answer there.